# Angular 2: Displaying result of Observable in model

Tags: angular, rendering, observable

We have a model which contains `Observable`'s. It's basically a "proxied" graph database. An object in JavaScript is a vertex in remote graph database. Getting a value of a property, if not primitive, is done through `Observable` and a HTTP request.

How can I effectively render such model in Angular 2?

One thing I could try is a 1:1 copy of the model class, only with normal reference instead of `Observable`, and filling that on return.

Also, my case is that I need a property of the object returned by the observable. In this, `statsFilesByTypeJavaPercent` is the `Observable`:

```
Java {{technologiesStats?.statsFilesByTypeJavaPercent?.quantity}} %
```

So how do I consume it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, got it... one can use `AsyncPipe`, with the syntax `... | async` pipe in Angular 2 templates:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items | async">{{item}}</li>
```

Pretty useful. Here is [some tutorial on the topic](http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/).

Then if one needs a property of an object given by `Observable`, this is the syntax:

```
Java {{(technologiesStats.statsFilesByTypeJavaPercent | async)?.quantity}} %
```

Also I think I could create a special component for that would take the result as an input and show the `.quantity`.